# Query ParseObject by objectId returning in different order?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm querying a set of ParseObjects, by their objId. I've added all the objectIds to a list. But when Parse returns the query, it doesn't return it in the order of objectIds I've provided. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

I've used Collections.reverse(), but that's pointless as sometimes the objects are returned in the order as the objIdList, sometimes they are not.

Is there a way to ensure that the ParseObjects-List returned is in the same order as the objIdList?

**Snippet for query**

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Alarm");
    query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
    //Collections.reverse(objIdList);
    query.whereContainedIn("objectId", objIdList);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) 
        {
            //Objects is a list of Alarms by the user that need to be added
            if(objects!=null)
            {

                pExistingAlarmList.addAll(objects);
                Collections.reverse(pExistingAlarmList);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit** 
A workaround for this which Im using for now is to query each objectId individually. That works perfectly. 
But if it could be done in a single query it
d be great!

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Alarm");
    query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
    // Retrieve the object by id
    query.getInBackground(objId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>()
    {
      public void done(ParseObject alarmObject, ParseException e) 
      {
        if (e == null) 
        {
            //Use alarmObject
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: never use android sdk but I am sure you need to do orderBy  `query.addAscendingOrder("objectId");`

Comment: but I needed it to return the objects in the order i've passed in. Ascending/Descending may not always match the order in which ive passed the objectIds

Answer (score 0):

`Adding` and `Arraylist` may help, by going thoroughly for each object for saving their `objectId` to the `arrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> objectsId = new ArrayList<String>();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Alarm");
query.whereEqualTo("user", user);
query.whereContainedIn("objectId", objIdList);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
{
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) 
    {
        //Objects is a list of Alarms by the user that need to be added
        if(objects!=null)
        {
          for(ParseObject object : objects){
          String objectId = object.get("objectId");
          objectsId.add(objectId);
          }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How's the for loop different from doing an addAll() ; won't I face the same problem ?